# Regex to not match digit or dot

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string I want to clean:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', '$14.99')
'1499'
```

How would I get it to `14.99` with the `.` in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the dot (or any other special regex symbol):

`>>> re.sub(r'[^\d\.]', '', '$14.99')
'14.99'`

Comment: why isn't it `[^\d|\.]` adding in an "or" ?

Comment: Because this is the purpose and behaviour of `[]`, as per the regex documentation: any single char, char class, char range, char pattern in the brackets is accepted, no special regex syntax needed. Note that `[\d\.]` is equivalent to `(\d|\.)` -- the round braces are the regex syntax for grouping. E.g., here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax (scroll down to `[]`).

Comment: You actually don't need to escape `.` when it's inside square brackets. It is treated as a literal character in this case. `[^\d.]` is exactly the same as `[^\d\.]`

Comment: However I should also add that `[^.]` is identical to `[^\d.]`, since `.` contains `\d`.

Comment: @CAustin `[^.]` is not identical to `[^\d.]`. Inside square brackets `[]`, the dot `.` is treated as a literal character dot `.` which doesn't contain `\d`.